# vba to remove string upto specific word

Tags: excel, vba

I have a string with value "NA - Phase 1:  Preliminary Phase" and I want to remove all the words before the dash "-".

Here is my current code, I am able to remove the string, but it keeps the "-", which I also want to remove.

```
indexOfThey = InStr(1, s, "-")
finalString = VBA.Mid(s, indexOfThey)
wksSourced.Cells(lastrowd + 1, 9).Value = finalString
```

Comment: If you know the dash is always followed by a space, you can just use `Mid(s, indexOfThey + 2)`

Comment: why don't use excel functions in VBA WorksheetFunction Library.

Comment: =RIGHT(G14,LEN(G14)-FIND("-",G14))   ' G14 is the cell referencing to the data

Answer (score 1):

You can just replace it directly:

```
wksSourced.Cells(lastrowd + 1, 9).Replace "*- ", "", xlPart
```

Comment: but I want to remove all the words Eg: "NA - " and not only "-"

Answer (score 0):

I would want to make the modification of the cell contents conditional on there being a dash in it in the first place. I should also like to trim any blank spaces that may remain after the removal. Therefore I would modify your original code like this:-

```
n = InStr(S, "-")
If n Then wksSourced.Cells(lastrowd + 1, 9).Value = Trim(Mid(S, n + 1))
```

However, if the string `S` is already resident in the specified cell the same idea would be expressed like this:-

```
With wksSourced.Cells(lastrowd + 1, 9)
    n = InStr(.Value, "-")
    If n Then .Value = Trim(Mid(.Value, n + 1))
End With
```